# What happens when a permanent True Polymorphed creature drops to 0?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, polymorph

Assume that a creature was True Polymorphed for the entire duration of the spell and is thus permanently transformed.

When said creature drops to 0, does the creature revert to it's previous form or does it die?

Can you stack True Polymorphs to create an possibly infinite HP pool?